# "ip route get" on Ubuntu returning default instead of static route

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iproute

We've been trying to solve this seemingly simple routing problem for days. We are trying to route traffic through an OpenVPN tunnel. Specifically, traffic to 10.0.1.136 should be routed through our tunnel interface. Thus we've added the route " 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0  metric 101" via ip route. However, as you can see below, if we do an "ip route get 10.0.1.136", the eth0 interface is selected.

We have tried:

- Deleting the cache
- Removing the default route
- Adding a route specifically for 10.0.1.136
- Making the route "static"

What are we missing? Are there any obvious problems in our routing table?

```
xx@xx:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.150 dev eth0 
10.0.0.2 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0  metric 101 
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.2.1 dev tun0  metric 101 
10.0.2.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.16.0.0/16 via 172.16.0.100 dev tap0 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.100 
192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 

xx@x:~$ sudo ip route get 10.0.1.136
10.0.1.136 via 192.168.10.150 dev eth0  src 192.168.10.100 
    cache 

xx@xx:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:57:a7:68  
          inet addr:192.168.10.100  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::468a:5bff:fe57:a768/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:711182 errors:0 dropped:237 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:715366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:88619834 (88.6 MB)  TX bytes:86802607 (86.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1388042 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1388042 (1.3 MB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:20:92:30:1c:9d  
          inet addr:172.16.0.100  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1420:92ff:fe30:1c9d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4759 errors:0 dropped:183 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:497307 (497.3 KB)  TX bytes:469035 (469.0 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.0.2.50  P-t-P:10.0.2.50  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:264830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:259659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:21013005 (21.0 MB)  TX bytes:23064408 (23.0 MB)
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but why are you setting a metric?

Comment: @Zoredache That line (with the metric) was originally added by OpenVPN automatically, so we have just been copying it. There's no reason other than that.